# Volley give me Out of memory exception after I make a lot of request with big amount of data

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-volley

I have a Page Viewer and inside every page I have list View , this list view will have 10 records using a web service , so the page viewer use three calls of the web service to populate three pages (the current , the left and the right page) but after I make a lot of swipes I am getting this exception :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (stack size 16384 bytes) failed: Try again
            at java.lang.VMThread.create(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1029)
            at com.android.volley.RequestQueue.start(RequestQueue.java:142)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:66)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:78)
            at com.imona.android.entities.Record.<init>(Record.java:57)
            at com.imona.android.webservices.OperationalDataRest$1.onResponse(OperationalDataRest.java:109)
            at com.imona.android.webservices.OperationalDataRest$1.onResponse(OperationalDataRest.java:85)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
            at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: did you have image in your View pager? did you extends `FragmentPagerAdapter` in your app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How do you initialize your `RequestQueue`? I suspect that you are creating `RequestQueue`s for each tab. If that's the case, change your program to use one common instance of `RequestQueue` from all the tabs. You need to initialize and retain it in your activity and add requests to it from each tab.

Comment: but I thought that Request Queue is singleton and I will not have another instance of it ? and if not you mean it is possible to have multiple request in the same time to the server called by multiple request queues. is it right ?

Comment: I discovered the answer before watching your post However thanks very much, it was Great answer :)

Comment: How do I do this? Is there any example of this? I'm facing the same problem. I guess it is because I put too many instances of Volleys in an activity.

Comment: I also face this type of problem. if any one have example then please let us know to understand what happen. In my case I make base class of volley and it extends every activity and I pass each time context to volley function. detail code is here http://androidpostbybhavik.blogspot.in/2015/11/generalize-web-api-calling-using-google.html?view=classic

Answer (score 4):

I used static queue instead of creating new queue in my Record class

I changed code from

```
public class Record {

    private RequestQueue RecordSyncQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ImonaAndroidApp.app);

}
```

to

```
public class Record {

    private static RequestQueue RecordSyncQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ImonaAndroidApp.app);

}
```