# Volley library getting out of memory error

Tags: android, android-volley

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1465140570 byte allocation with 1622964 free bytes and 509MB until OOM
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:316)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readString(DiskBasedCache.java:526)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readStringStringMap(DiskBasedCache.java:548)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CacheHeader.readHeader(DiskBasedCache.java:392)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.initialize(DiskBasedCache.java:155)
    at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:85)
```

Comment: This is mostly because of we don't know that how large data or file app can load whenever we used large data or file to load statically it cause error with some device which dont have enough memory so.. try to use small sizes file..

Answer (score 10):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35259579/5287072) help, I'm testing It, when I finish, I will come here to write if It works

---

### update

Well I tested It with an infinite cycle

like this

```
//global var 
Boolean running = true;
Thread MyThread = new Thread(){//create thread
    @Override
    public void run() {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyActivity.this);// start one time no more...
    String url = "http://192.168.1.78/testget.php?key=123456789"; // my URL

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {//where request return ...
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println("Volley response: \"" + response +"\"");
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("There is an error: "+error.getMessage()); // on error, ex: URL bad... internet down, etc..
        }
    });
    stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);// no caching url...
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(
            new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    20000,//time to wait for it in this case 20s
                    20,//tries in case of error
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
            )
    );

        
        int i=0;
        while(running){
            
            System.out.println("counter: "+i);
            i++;
            
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Sleep interrupted");
            }
            
            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            queue.add(stringRequest);
        }
        System.out.println("onEnd Thread");
    }
};
MyThread.start(); // start thread

//in some button declare 
running=false;
```

I tested it ***130144 times*** ~ 18.07 hr, without any error

```
System.out: Counter: 130141
System.out: Volley response: "something"
System.out: Counter: 130142
System.out: Volley response: "something"
System.out: Counter: 130143
System.out: Volley response: "something"
System.out: Counter: 130144
```

---

### Getting Error with call `newRequestQueue` more than one time

Test with `RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyActivity.this);` calling more than one time

**Example:**

```
//global var 
Boolean running = true;

Thread MyThread = new Thread(){//create thread

    void getSomethingFromSite(){
        
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyActivity.this);//calling request more than one time... error you not call more than one time
        String url = "http://192.168.1.78/testget.php?key=123456789"; // my url

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {//where request return ...
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println("Volley response: \"" + response +"\"");
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    System.out.println("There is an error: "+error.getMessage()); // on error, ex: URL bad... internet down, etc..
            }
        });
        stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);// no caching url...
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(
                new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                        20000,//time to wait for it in this case 20s
                        20,//tries in case of error
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
                )
        );
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            
        int i=0;
        while(running){
            
            System.out.println("counter: "+i);
            i++;
            
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Sleep interrupted");
            }
            //call volley 
            getSomethingFromSite();
        }
        System.out.println("onEnd Thread");
    }
};
MyThread.start(); // start thread

//in some button declare 
running false;
```

**Erro with 475 times**

```
I/System.out: Counter: 471
I/System.out: Volley response: "Something"
W/libc: pthread_create failed: couldn't allocate 1064960-byte stack: Out of memory
E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again"
       --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-373
  Process: com.masm.testservice, PID: 3821
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
      at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
      at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
      at com.android.volley.RequestQueue.start(RequestQueue.java:152)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:66)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:78)
      at com.masm.testservice.MyService$1.getDataVolley(MyService.java:84)
      at com.masm.testservice.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:129)
E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.os.Parcel.nativeWriteString(Native Method)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeString(Parcel.java:536)
        at android.app.ApplicationErrorReport$CrashInfo.writeToParcel(ApplicationErrorReport.java:389)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4099)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:89)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

---

### Conclusion

You do not call `newRequestQueue` more than one time...
you will get error of `out memory` or `OOM` error.

More links for reference or information:
1.- [Out of memory error when use volley library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35259579/5287072)
2.- [Volley give me Out of memory exception after I make a lot of request with big amount of data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21476326/5287072)
3.- [Volley slow and causing memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19479785/5287072)
4.- [Volley framewok request keeps objects in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868608/volley-framewok-request-keeps-objects-in-memory)

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still encounters this issue, it [was fixed](https://github.com/google/volley/issues/12) on volley version [1.1.0-rc1](https://github.com/google/volley/releases/tag/1.1.0-rc1)

Just upgrade to this version.

Answer (score 1):

OutOfMemoryError occurs when you try to load large data into your app's memory that exceeds the available RAM. I do not know what you are using volley for at the moment but try disabling cache for volley [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562398/volley-disable-cache-for-one-request) or not load a huge file at once or try compressing the file. It would help if you give more detail on what you are trying to achieve and the code section that is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is thrown while trying to read the header, which should be comparatively small. Note as well that the DiskBasedCache size is only 5MB.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42196956/901597